# Mm2 on kafka connect stops replicating topic after DisconnectException

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I have 3 kafka-connect nodes, running mm2 tasks.
Those task replicate 4 topics from remote uk and us clusters into single uk kafka cluster.

Everything works fine most of the time, but at some point I noticed that the lag on 1 of the topics started increasing.

Watching the logs, I’ve noticed this in the beginning of the lag growing:

```
[2023-10-21 05:05:56,820] INFO [mm2-msc-us-dc1-2-live|task-19] [Consumer clientId=mm2-us-dc1-2-live->mm2-kafka|mm2-msc-us-dc1-2-live-19|replication-consumer, groupId=null] Disconnecting from node 895 due to request timeout. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:836)
[2023-10-21 05:05:56,821] INFO [mm2-msc-us-dc1-2-live|task-19] [Consumer clientId=mm2-us-dc1-2-live->mm2-kafka|mm2-msc-us-dc1-2-live-19|replication-consumer, groupId=null] Cancelled in-flight FETCH request with correlation id 1215447 due to node 895 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 30025ms, elapsed time since send: 30025ms, request timeout: 30000ms) (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:344)
[2023-10-21 05:05:56,821] INFO [mm2-msc-us-dc1-2-live|task-19] [Consumer clientId=mm2-us-dc1-2-live->mm2-kafka|mm2-msc-us-dc1-2-live-19|replication-consumer, groupId=null] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=1799400446, epoch=1214974) to node 895: (org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler:615)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException
```

the chart with lag (it uses +3 offset, so literally it started at the same time as in logs above:
[image: the chart with lag]

Any idea what can be the reason? Why it stopped replicating only 1 topic and why it fixed itself in 1.5 hour?

Comment: Maybe the broker 895 experienced a brief failure or restart and as a consequence it caused the disconnect and timeouts. And why the lag only appears in one topic ? Maybe It is the only topic that has experienced a high load of data at this point of time. Also the number of partitions has an impact on replication.

Comment: I have 2 high load topics, and the failing one was the 2nd. The question is: why didn't mm2 continue fetching the data after the disconnect? And why it took so many time for it to restore? It just doesn't make sense (doesn't fit any kafka timeout settings)

Comment: For many reasons:
It could be the time taken by mm2 to reestablish a new session and it will took more time if there was a network issue. Also, it could be the time to catch up during a fetch operation that has been not successful due to the disconnection. So you may need to check the configurations of batch sizes , commit intervals, retries ...

Comment: Do your topics have the same number of partitions / republication factor ? Does  Your broker 895 have partitions of both of these 2 topics ? The data load of the other topic was in the same moment of the connection issue ?

Comment: yes, both topics are on that broker 895. yes, they have the same number of partitions. Both has the same replication factor 1.